# jQuery - prevent option deselect in select multiple

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to prevent an option from being deselected in a select multiple control? Also it must not deselect any other selected options. I have tried:

```
$('#selections option').click(function(){
    $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Doesn't seem to work. Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: options don't generally trigger mouse events, so I would say no ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it

```
$('#selections').on('change', function(e) {
    var self = this,
        selected = $(this).data('selected') || [];

    $.each(selected, function(_,i) {
        $('option', self).eq(i).prop('selected', true)
    });

    $(this).data('selected', $.map($('option:selected', this), function(el) {
        return $(el).index();
    }));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/p8D5Y/)

Answer (score 0):

already tried this?:

```
$('#selections option').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $(this).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Comment: If you're proposing this solution then suggest it rather than questioning it. And also explain why this works by [edit]ing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#selections").click(function () {
    $("#option_always_selected").prop('selected', true);
});
```